# know the best method to pass the routing variable more than 5 in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

html

```
<a href="{{path('href="{{path('stockitemdetails_category_report',{'itemcode':itemcode,'category':category,'subcategory':subcategory})}}">
```

stockregister.yml (Routing file)

```
 stockregister_report_itemcode_search:
                    pattern:  /stockregister/itemcode/data
                    defaults: { _controller: "EduAssetBundle:StockRegister:stockregisterItemcodeDate" }
                    requirements:
                        itemcode: .+
                        category: .+
                        subcategory: .+
                        type: .+
                        accountunit: .+



     Controller(File) 
 public function stockregisterItemcodeDateAction($itemcode,$category,$type,$accountunit) {}
```

here is the routing file where i define the variable which i have to pass but the problem is that the variable values is dynamic user can write anything.
    according to values in controller the dynamic values access and i can run query.
    but the problem is that the url value will be any thing.

Comment: its a bit unclear what you're trying to do.  Can the data come from a form?  This seems like a very clunky way of doing it.  I get the feeling you need to look at your approach to the problem.  Can you tell us what the use case is? Passing it all in in a query string looks very insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `.+` is greedy, so it will match everything it finds - including the slash. So `itemcode` wil match the whole of the path, as the router won't be able to work out whether a slash is part of or the end of the itemcode parameter.

You could encode the values, so that unencoded slashes indicate the end of a parameter, whereas encoded slashes are part of the parameter value. Then you could remove the regex.

The better solution is just to use GET, instead of making them part of the path. When you generate a URL using the router, any variables that aren't mapped in the path will be appended as GET variables anyway. If necessary, you could build a `ParamConverter` to automatically inject the GET variables as parameters into the action.